# Infer type of object property to be passed to object function as argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I'm trying to define a function that accepts an object with a data type and a function that gets that data type as it's argument.

```
const test = <
  Data extends object,
  C extends {init: Data; serialize: (d: Data) => any}
>(
  component: C
) => {}
```

But when I try to use it, TypeScript can only infer the `object` data type that the `Data` type extends and not the actual shape of the `Data` property:

```
test({
  init: {opa: 'super'},
  serialize: (data) => {
    // Property 'opa' does not exist on type 'object'
    return data.opa
  }
})
```

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=3&pln=8&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YB4CwAoGMAiAhlATPAB4JgAmEMIARgFbzBQA02uAwqRfNbQDeASzDCoALnxECAbhgR4AJ2EEANsIBe8KQAoqUwsQCUKAHwwCYAJ4BfbGd2cYoALYAHcP0kwu2U8gWgvZY2AjQuoLOouJSgiDuBFIA5BAAru7KybYcOArKqhraelQyAUHOuAD0VTAACkoJylDWMMkJBMkwVCCIMGAgsOTCSOBw1pltDMysyZUwSvBQaUpg3TIAdB3OIbbGQA)

How do I define `Data` so that TypeScript can correctly infer it's shape?

Answer (score 0):

`C` doesn't need to be a type parameter, just make it the type of `component`:

```typescript
const test = <
    Data extends object
>(
    component: {init: Data; serialize: (d: Data) => any} // <====
) => {
};

test({
    init: {opa: 'super'},
    serialize: (data) => {
        return data.opa;
    }
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YB4CwAoGuYBEBDKQmeADwTABMIYQAjAK3mCmwD4AKbPGUALYAHcPDBQAXDADeASzCzJBYoQDcMCPABOswgBtZAL3hSu1KURIBKFBxiEwATwC%202G8jvTsz1dmwJoLi8cPHlFKWkQIUIpAHIIAFchbVjnABpePE0dfSMTGDMVd09MvlwteCgErTAYahUAOii1UphXLGcrVSA)

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do something similar for a React+TS Component interface? asking for a friend ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71836109/incompatible-function-argument-in-component-props