# incompatible function argument in component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a component that takes a list of items, known to have an ID, and a function that filters those items.

The type with an ID is a generic type of item, that all items will have.

But more specific items will include other props.

```
type GenericItem = {
    id: string;
}

type SpecificItem = {
    id: string;
    someOtherProp: boolean;
}
```

I also have a function type, that uses the generic type to operate on.

```
type GenericItemFunction = (item: GenericItem) => boolean;
```

I then have this component that uses the GenericItem and GenericItemFunction in its props.

```
type CompProps = {
    fn: GenericItemFunction;
    items: GenericItem[];
}
const Comp: React.FC<CompProps> = ({ fn, items }) => <></>;
```

When I try to use this component with the Specific type, I am getting errors saying I cannot use an implementation of GenericItemFunction because the types for item are not compatible.

```
const App = () => {
    const items: SpecificItem[] = [];
    const filter = (item: SpecificItem) => item.someOtherProp;

    return (
        <Comp
            fn={filter}     // error on `fn` prop
            items={items}
        />
    )
}
```

The typescript error I receive is:

```
Type '(item: SpecificItem) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'GenericItemFunction'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.
    Property 'someOtherProp' is missing in type 'GenericItem' but required in type 'SpecificItem'.
```

I guess I have two questions;

Firstly, Why is there a conflict when both types expect the `id: string` property?

Secondly, is there a more sane way to do something like this?

My first though was the type for `item` on the `GenericItemFunction` could be inferred from the value provided to the `items` prop in the App component.

But to be completely honest, I'm not sure how that would look...

My other thought was to have the `Comp` be a generic, but not show to use a react component that uses generics... Seems like jsx/tsx doesn't really support that syntax.

I expect something like this to throw all sorts of errors.

```
const Comp = <T extends GenericItem,>({ fn, items }) => <></>;

const App = () => {
 return <Comp<SpecificType> />;
}
```

Finally, I did try this and there aren't any errors. But the downside is the type for `items` is inferred to be any.

```
type GenericItem = {
    id: string;
}

type SpecificItem = {
    id: string;
    someOtherProp: boolean;
}

type GenericItemFunction <T> = (item: T) => boolean;


type CompProps <T extends GenericItem = any> = {
    fn: GenericItemFunction<T>;
    items: T[];
}
const Comp: React.FC<CompProps> = ({ fn, items }) => <></>;

const App = () => {
    const items: SpecificItem[] = [];
    const filter = (item: SpecificItem) => item.someOtherProp;

    return (
        <Comp
            fn={filter}
            items={items}
        />
    )
}
```

Here's a link to the playground I've been using.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgSWBAtlAvFAN4BQAkCgCYBcUAzsKvAOYDcJAviSaJFAMqQ0KAGbosuAsRJRZUKrQZM2MuXQD2OCAHlgAC2QAFJOrC0ARuvUAbCAEN47Lj3DQ4iVJmw4AYgFd4NGAUdXgoAB4AFQA+KQAKFG9aSIBKAljLG3tHbhc+AGFNMGNTOgjIqAgAD2x4SjL3ZHFvKQcQWMJSMhF4WkbPCV8AoJD4KOj2OXlvOmSAbQBdJxI0UIYoQpwzKAAleyCAOh988M3ikzA6Dqg4oigegBpp3DKONPxY8OjwgHoJ7lW8HWAEEwGB4u9YqQpoD1okXrRBBBhGIvLhFlJFpM5LDgPcUNZsEh4vCcIihKJmrhIc8cAcNFpdAYkCUwOxVLIkBBgH4kGE4hyphEzoKhXIevgiGJCcguGKxaS6JLFXL5X9BSlOEA

***UPDATE:***

> Why did you use any as default for GenericItem type? Without this I believe it should properly infer Genericitem from GenericItemFunction. – tymzap

Removing the `= any` for the `CompProps` typedef causes errors in the `Comp` declaration...

```
type CompProps <T extends GenericItem> = {
    fn: GenericItemFunction<T>;
    items: T[];
}
const Comp: React.FC<CompProps> = ({ fn, items }) => <></>; // this line has the error
```

```
Generic type 'CompProps' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

Meaning, I still have to declare the type somewhere. Meaning I need to know the variation of the `GenericItem` type before I use the component.

`SpecificItem` is just a representation of the types that happen to overlap with the `GenericItem` typedef.

In most cases, the `Comp` wont know what type will actually be used and any doesn't give any useful information to the author.

I'm hoping for something like...

```
type CompProps <T extends GenericItem> = {
    items: <T extends GenericItem>[];
    fn: <infer from T>[];
}
```

But I'm not sure if this exists, or something like it.

Comment: Why did you use `any` as default for `GenericItem` type? Without this I believe it should properly infer `Genericitem` from `GenericItemFunction`.

Comment: I did find this ts playgound, but couldn't figure out how to reproduce it with a typedef.

Found in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/71748171/5548721

In this, there is a type expected for the `test` function's argument.

It has `{ init: Data, serialise: (d: Data) => any }`

But the type of Data is inferred from the value passed when the method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:face_palm:

The `CompProps` using `<T extends GenericType = any>` is the correct way to do this.

```
type CompProps <T extends GenericItem = any> = {
    items: T[];
    filter: (item: T) => boolean;
}
const Comp: React.FC<CompProps> = (props) => <></>;
```

The magic is happening here:

```
const App = () => {
    ...
    const filter = (item: SpecificItem) => item.someOtherProp;
    ...
}
```

The `const Comp: React.FC<CompProps>` doesn't care what the generic type is, hence `= any`. As long as it has at least the same shape as `GenericType`.

But inside the `App` component, where we are defining the method for the filter prop, we are declaring the `SpecificItem` typedef in the argument. Only *that* method uses the `SpecificItem` typedef. `CompProps` only cares it meets the required shape of `GenericItem`.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: I've taken your original playground and then replaced `CompProps` and `Comp` with what you have above: https://tsplay.dev/m3yv2w It has an error on `fn={filter}`: *"Type '{ fn: (item: SpecificItem) => boolean; items: SpecificItem[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CompProps<any>'. Property 'fn' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CompProps<any>'.(2322)"* Is there something else I need to do to see what you're doing? (I ask because I suspect it doesn't actually work, and don't want you [or others] to get bitten by it *seeming* to work and then letting you down.)

Answer (score -1):

> In most cases, the `Comp` wont know what type will actually be used and any doesn't give any useful information to the author.

To me, that means `Comp` is generic. So I would remove the `= any` on `CompProps`:

```typescript
type CompProps<T extends GenericItem> = {
    fn: GenericItemFunction<T>;
    items: T[];
};
```

...and then define `Comp` as generic. There's probably a way to do that with `React.FC`, but personally I don't use `React.FC` so I don't know what it is. :-) `React.FC` doesn't do much of anything for you, and [as some people point out](https://blog.raccoons.be/react-fc-opinion), amongst other things it says your component accepts `children` whether it does or not. I prefer to be explicit about it when my components accept `children`.

So I'd define `Comp` like this:

```typescript
const Comp = <T extends GenericItem>({ fn, items }: CompProps<T>) => {
    // Just to show that `fn` and `items` play together:
    const example = items.map(fn);
    return <>{example}</>;
};
```

If you wanted it to have children, you can add them easily enough. Use `string` if you only want to support text, or `React.Node` if you want to allow just about anything:

```typescript
// Does allow children:
type Comp2Props<T extends GenericItem> = {
    fn: GenericItemFunction<T>;
    items: T[];
    children: React.ReactNode;
};
const Comp2 = <T extends GenericItem>({ fn, items, children }: Comp2Props<T>) => {
    // Just to show that `fn` and `items` play together:
    const example = items.map(fn);
    return <>{example}</>;
};
```

Either way, it works well in your scenario:

```typescript
const App = () => {
    const items: SpecificItem[] = [];
    const filter = (item: SpecificItem) => item.someOtherProp;

    return <>
        <Comp
            fn={filter}
            items={items}
        />
    </>;
};
```

And the types mean it doesn't work in places you probably don't want it to:

```typescript
const App2 = () => {
    const genericItems: GenericItem[] = [];
    const filterGeneric = (item: GenericItem) => item.id === "example"; // Silly definition, but...
    const specificItems: SpecificItem[] = [];
    const filterSpecific = (item: SpecificItem) => item.someOtherProp;

    return <>
        {/* Desirable error, `fn` can't handle `GenericItem`s, only `SpecificItem`s */}
        <Comp
            fn={filterSpecific}
            items={genericItems}
        />

        {/* Works, `fn` handles the supertype of the items, which is fine */}
        <Comp
            fn={filterGeneric}
            items={specificItems}
        />

        {/* Desirable error because `Comp` doesn't [now] support `children` */}
        <Comp
            fn={filterSpecific}
            items={specificItems}
        >
            children here
        </Comp>

        {/* Works because `Comp2` does support `children`*/}
        <Comp2
            fn={filterSpecific}
            items={specificItems}
        >
            children here
        </Comp2>
    </>;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-lePVQThPMB1F1fZ0AIVYDQLbAQIOqKC5RgiUFhQvZU1ItCBAwxcr2RH48J7DgCLKPSUPI+INQkEw+AEfBvyQMglwuLQfiCUUGwMZhSjWNE-CSSsNQ1YyYJkYjkPjXSEKQ-TDnQgtoIU0zcLYRKSLQKzeCIxDcvjOzeEo6iz3oyhGMlD9sjyIShFOAAqK5bmAKAUD8VU2BwKA0TZZgOTQLlHjgNwuXEVUWQslCWRkNEMl8nkcri+J5rgZrTgkyT2NaRqHB4vizOy2KOB2ySLHVXitLjDELq46TGsEFq4AAdWgABrBaeR3CbBhCYYpVkJI6FgRoIEwRkPBEn63m+L5LGGAL6C2h62I4y7DuYXj+LYWb0ck67BBioq1t2QmpIa57XsudrOu6+heugOA-EQlAqXoFkgw5cQbjuMb9mYd4UpkUHIFgHlR3+Dk0cavbwAO7iceOrKoFW86ldzDFeNJpKdMpuAGqxuVvhLFhxrYJB5dOINqcul7Wo+qBvtZ9nOZ5Vtef5kHQOgVlpZYFk5cuhWQy1gdcZO9WzrQQ3th1knY-iw3jZNz4zbHS2iBt1s0-Me1HWdIA)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good solution for scaling the number of `SpecificType`s. Not sure if i made it clear but in my real example there are dozens of specific types. Are you suggesting that each specific type would have it's own `CompProps` interface and require it's own `Comp` component?

Comment: I understand your point about the children prop, but considering this is a contrived example, it seems off topic. Also, you still cannot do `<Comp<SpecificType>> />` in jsx. So I'm still unsure how generic types help here.

Comment: @Lawrence_NT - No, I'm not talking about every specific type requiring its own `Comp` component. Look at the code above: `Comp` has nothing in it that's specific to `SpecificType`. You can use it with as many different `SpecificType`s you want, as long as they're assignment-compatible with `GenericType`.

Comment: An error from your example that you linked. `Type 'GenericItem[]' is not assignable to type 'SpecificItem[]'.
  Property 'someOtherProp' is missing in type 'GenericItem' but required in type 'SpecificItem'.` Effectively the same problem in the original post. When using the component, the types are not compatible, even though they are the same shape.

Comment: @Lawrence_NT - The only errors in the [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mp9xXW) I gave are **intentional** ones to show that misuse is flagged up. (This is quite normal in TypeScript circles -- it's as important to show mistakes are caught as to show that things work.) Read the comments.